# Perl — Calculate timing difference in microseconds

Tags: perl

I want to get time difference of below strings using Perl:

1. `2013-12-27 13:28:14.975952`
2. `2013-12-27 13:28:16.345667` (microseconds).

I tried using `mktime` and getting millisec since the epoch but it’s not helping much.

If I use [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3A%3AHiRes) module, how can I convert the above times to get the difference?  Or do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: I removed the leading zero from the second fraction since 7 digits mean that the value is no longer in microseconds but in tenths of microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
   on_error  => 'croak',
   time_zone => 'local',
);

sub parse_datetime {
   my ($str) = @_;

   my $nano;
   if ($str =~ /^([^.]*)\.(\d+)\z/) {
      $str = $1;
      $nano = "0.$2" * 1_000_000_000;
   } else {
      $nano = 0;
   }

   return $format->parse_datetime($str)->add( nanoseconds => $nano );
}

sub diff {
   return
      $_[1]->subtract_datetime_absolute($_[0])
         ->in_units('nanoseconds')
            / 1_000_000_000
}

my $dt1 = parse_datetime('2013-12-27 13:28:14.975952');
my $dt2 = parse_datetime('2013-12-27 13:28:16.0345667');
my $diff = diff($dt1, $dt2);
print("$diff\n");
```

But I'm a little confused. nothing in Time::HiRes returns something like `2013-12-27 13:28:14.975952`. If you are actually using `Time::HiRes::time`, you can use the following:

```
use DateTime qw( );

sub diff {
   return
      $_[1]->subtract_datetime_absolute($_[0])
         ->in_units('nanoseconds')
            / 1_000_000_000
}

my $dt1 = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => 1388461836.975952,  time_zone => 'local' );
my $dt2 = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => 1388461838.0345667, time_zone => 'local' );
my $diff = diff($dt1, $dt2);
print("$diff\n");
```

Comment: Thanks but i dont have DateTime::Format:: installed, any better way to do it ?

Comment: Of course not. I would have posted it. There are certainly *worse* ways of doing it, and there might even be equally good ways. Why do you ask?

Comment: Sir thanks for post, i did like it and its good. Just that i dont have DateTime::Format not installed.

Comment: Sir thanks for post, i did like it and its good. Just that i dont have DateTime::Format not installed. Will try to go with second option. Can you tell me how to get epoch i am using below methord to get epoch  my $seconds = mktime( @mktime_args, 0, 0, $dst );

Answer (score 1):

If [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) and [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) isn't an option, [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aPiece) has been in core since 5.10.

```
use Time::Piece;

sub str2time {
    my ($str) = @_;
    $str =~ s/(\.[0-9]+)?\z//;
    my $fraction = $1 || 0;
    return Time::Piece->strptime($str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')->epoch + $fraction;
}

my $t1 = str2time('2013-12-27 13:28:14.975952');
my $t2 = str2time('2013-12-27 13:28:16.345667');

printf "difference: %f\n", $t2 - $t1;
```

Comment: Nice answer, though we need to discourage this "I can't install things" B.S.